# How does one make a Dart object/class indexable?

Tags: object, indexing, dart

In Python I can make any class support indexing by overriding `__getitem__` like so:

```python
class Test:
   def __getitem__(self, key):
      return self.data[key]
```

Does Dart have a similar construct for this?

Answer (score 18):

Assuming that the `__getitem__` thing lets you use the "indexing" syntax (`object[index]`), yes, Dart lets you do the same by defining `operator []`. Example:

```dart
class Test {
  var data = {
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2
  };

  operator [](index) => data[index];
}

main() {
  var t = new Test();
  print(t["a"]);
  print(t["b"]);
}
```

You can also define the "opposite" `operator []=`:

```dart
class Test {
  Map data = {
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2
  };

  operator [](index) => data[index];
  operator []=(index, value) { data[index] = value; }
}

main() {
  var t = new Test();
  print(t["a"]);
  print(t["b"]);
  t["c"] = 3;
  print(t["c"]);
}
```