# Dart - Inserting an index to dart datastore object for Google Cloud Datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, dart, google-cloud-datastore

I am working on deploying Dart's [client-server example](https://github.com/dart-lang/appengine_samples/tree/master/clientserver) into my google app-engine. The data gets inserted into cloud datastore just fine. However, when the data gets queried, I get the following exception occurs whenever I make a GET request to query all the data.

```
13:04:19.191  Uncaught error in request handler: An index is needed for the query to succeed.
#0      catchAndReThrowDatastoreException.<anonymous closure> (package:appengine/src/api_impl/raw_datastore_v3_impl.dart:48:5)
#1      _rootRunBinary (dart:async/zone.dart:914)
#2      _CustomZone.runBinary (dart:async/zone.dart:812)
#3      _Future._propagateToListeners.handleError 
...
```

I did some [digging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16881852/how-does-one-make-a-dart-object-class-indexable) and found out that I can insert an index to the object by using an operator.

so my datastore object is now the following:

```dart
import 'package:gcloud/db.dart';

@Kind()
class Item extends Model {
  @StringProperty()
  String name;

  operator [](index) => name[index];
  Map serialize() => {'name': name};
  static Item deserialize(Map json) => new Item()..name = json['name'];
}
```

However, the same exception still gets thrown when I make a get request to query all the data.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the `index.yaml` file is missing in your deploy command

```bash
gcloud preview app deploy app.yaml index.yaml
```

It's highlighted in a blue box here but I also missed it the first time:
https://www.dartlang.org/server/google-cloud-platform/app-engine/deploy.html

Comment: Hey Gunter - yes, this was indeed an issue. After deploying it this command everything worked :)